# Undetermined Coefficients trouble

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to solve $y'' + 4y = \sin^3(2x)$. However, I do not know what guess I would use for $g(x) = \sin^3(2x)$ since it is cubed. Usually, when $g(x) = b\sin(\beta x)$, I would give a guess for the particular solution as: $A\cos(\beta x) + B\sin(\beta x)$.

Would anyone mind pushing me in the right direction to solve this differential equation?

Comment: For reference, the solution is $y(x)=A\sin(2x)+B\cos(2x)+\frac{1}{128}\sin(6x)-\frac{3}{16}x\cos(2x)$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: $\sin(3\theta)=3\sin(\theta)-4\sin^3(\theta)$

Answer (score 1):

Use this trigonometric identity of $\sin^3 \theta = \frac 34 \sin \theta - \frac 14 \sin(3\theta)$. ([Source](https://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080723124442AAcZCTX))

If we let $\theta =2x$, then we have $$\sin^3 (2x) = \frac 34 \sin(2x) - \frac 14 \sin(6x).$$

Therefore, you can assume your particular solution of the form
$$y_p=A \sin (2x)+B\sin(6x).$$

Comment: How do we solve for $A$ and $B$ for the particular solution if the sines with the $A$ coefficient cancels out when we plug back into our non-homogeneous differential equation?